# Slashcommands doesn't work with my discord.js bot Collection(0) [Map] {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

hello everything is fine? I'm facing a problem with a discord bot. the bot starts normally, but the slash commands are not being registered because no options appear in the bot.

Node Version: v18.16.0

package.js

```js
{
  "name": "moomooo-mir4",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.3",
    "ascii-table": "^0.0.9",
    "discord.js": "^14.13.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pg": "^8.11.3"
  }
}
```

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── SECURITY.md
├── commands
│   └── slash\Player\pilot.js and register.js
├── config.js
├── database
│   └── psql.js
├── events
│   ├── client\ready.js
│   └── guild\slashHandler.js
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── structures
    ├── handlers\events.js and slashCommands.js
    └── lib\DiscordClient.js
```

index.js

```js
import { DiscordClient } from "./structures/lib/DiscordClient.js";
const client = new DiscordClient();

client.start();
console.log("Client started");

export { client };
```

config.js

```js
import "dotenv/config";
const config = {
  token: process.env.BOT_TOKEN,
  default_prefix: "m!",
  owners: ["676518256282042393", "327644167276855298"],
  presence: {
    activities: [
      {
        name: 'mir4info',
        type: 0,
      },
    ],
    status: 'online',
  }
}

export { config };
```

events.js

```js
import Ascii from 'ascii-table';
import fs from 'fs';
import { client } from "../../index.js";


class eventHandler {
    constructor() {};

    async run() {
        const eventsTable = new Ascii('Events').setHeading('Name', 'Status', 'Reason');
        const dirs = fs.readdirSync("./events");
        dirs.forEach(dir => {
            const files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dir}`);
            files.forEach(async (file) => {
                const module = await import(`../../events/${dir}/${file}`);
                const event = module.default;
                let name;
                if (!event.name || !event.run) {
                    return eventsTable.addRow(`${event.name || file}`, "Failed", "Missing Name/Run");
                }

                name = event.name;
                if (event.nick) {
                    name += ` (${event.nick})`;
                }

                if (event.once) {
                    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.run(...args, client));
                } else {
                    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.run(...args, client));
                }
                eventsTable.addRow(name, "Success");
                if (file=="slashHandler.js") {
                    console.log(eventsTable.toString());
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
export default new eventHandler();
```

slashCommands.js

```js
import Ascii from 'ascii-table';
import fs from 'fs';
import { client } from "../../index.js";
class slashHandler {
  constructor() {};
  async run() {
    const slashCommandsTable = new Ascii('Slash Commands').setHeading('Name', 'Status', 'Reason');
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync("./commands/slash");
    dirs.forEach(dir => {
      const files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/slash/${dir}`);
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
        const module = await import(`../../commands/slash/${dir}/${file}`);
        const command = module.default;
        let name;

        if (!command.name || !command.run) {
          return slashCommandsTable.addRow(`${command.name || file}`, "Failed", "Missing Name/Run");
        }

        name = command.name;
        if (command.nick) {
          name += ` (${command.nick})`;
        }

        if (!command.enabled) {
          return slashCommandsTable.addRow(`${name}`, "Failed", "Disabled");
        }

        client.slashCommands.set(command.name, command);
        slashCommandsTable.addRow(name, "Success");
        console.log(client.slashCommands);

        if (file=="register.js") {
          console.log(slashCommandsTable.toString());
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
export default new slashHandler();
```

ready.js

```js
import { client } from "../../index.js";
class Event {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "ready";
    };

    async run() {
        const commandArray = client.slashCommands;
        console.log(commandArray)
        client.application.commands.set(commandArray);
        client.user.setPresence(client.config.presence);

        client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
            client.database.getPlayer()
                .then(players => {
                    players.forEach(player => {
                        if (!guild.members.cache.get(`${player.user_id}`)) {
                            client.database.remPlayer({id: player.user_id})
                                .then(console.log)
                                .catch(console.error);
                        }
                    });
                    guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                        client.database.addPlayer(member.user)
                            .then(console.log)
                            .catch(console.error);
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    if (String(err).includes("Error 404")) {
                        guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                            client.database.addPlayer(member.user)
                                .then(console.log)
                                .catch(console.error);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}
export default new Event();
```

slashHandler.js

```js
import { EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js";
import { client } from "../../index.js";
class slashHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "interactionCreate";
        this.nick = "Slash";
    };
    /**
     * 
     * @param {import("discord.js").CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async run(interaction) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const command = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) {
                return interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setColor("Red")
                            .setTitle("Error 404: Command not found")
                            .setDescription("This Command doesn\'t exit within the Bot\'s files, please contact the Developer about this Issue.")
                            .setTimestamp()
                    ]
                });
            }
            if (command.permissions) {
                if (command.permissions.bot && command.permissions.bot.length && !interaction.channel.permissionsFor(interaction.guild.me).has(command.permissions.bot)) {
                    let perms = interaction.channel.permissionsFor(interaction.guild.me).missing(command.permissions.bot);
                    return interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [
                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                .setColor("Red")
                                .setTitle("Error 403: Bot missing Permission")
                                .setDescription("The Bot is missing the Permissions to run the command:\n" + perms.join(", "))
                                .setTimestamp()
                        ]
                    });
                }
            }
            command.run(client, interaction);
        }
    }
}
export default new slashHandler();
```

pilot.js

```js
import { ApplicationCommandOptionType, EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js";
class Command {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "pilot";
        this.description = "Pilot related Commands";
        this.options = [
            {
                name: "add",
                description: "Designate a Pilot for your Character",
                description_localizations: {
                    "en-US": "Designate a Pilot for your character",
                    "pt-BR": "Designar um Piloto para seu personagem",
                    "es-ES": "Designar un Piloto para tu personaje",
                    "zh-CN": "为您的角色指定飞行员",
                    "ko": "캐릭터에 대한 파일럿 지정"
                },
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                    {
                        name: "user",
                        description: "The pilot to add",
                        description_localizations: {
                            "en-US": "The pilot to add",
                            "pt-BR": "O piloto para adicionar",
                            "es-ES": "El piloto para agregar",
                            "zh-CN": "要添加的飞行员",
                            "ko": "추가 할 파일럿"
                        },
                        type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
                        required: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
    };

    async run(client, interaction) {
        const member = interaction.member
        const user = member.user;
        const option = interaction.options;
        const pilot = option.getUser("pilot");
        switch (option.getSubcommand()) {
            case "add":
                client.database.getCharacter(user)
                    .then(chars => {
                        const char = chars[0];
                        client.database.addPilot(user, pilot, char)
                            .then(async (msg) => {
                                const pilotmember = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(pilot.id);
                                await pilotmember.setNickname(`[Pilot] ${user.displayName}`);
                                await interaction.reply({
                                    embeds: [
                                        new EmbedBuilder()
                                            .setColor("Green")
                                            .setDescription(`${msg}`)
                                            .setTimestamp()
                                    ],
                                    ephemeral: true
                                });
                            })
                            .catch(async (err) => {
                                if (String(err).includes("Error 409")) {
                                    await interaction.reply({
                                        embeds: [
                                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                                .setColor("Red")
                                                .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                                .setDescription("You already registered a Pilot!")
                                                .setTimestamp()
                                        ],
                                        ephemeral: true
                                    });
                                } else if (String(err).includes("Error 404") && String(err).includes("Character")) {
                                    await interaction.reply({
                                        embeds: [
                                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                                .setColor("Red")
                                                .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                                .setDescription("Could not find a registered Character in the Database. Make sure to use \`/register\` before you use this Command!")
                                                .setTimestamp()
                                        ],
                                        ephemeral: true
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    await interaction.reply({
                                        embeds: [
                                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                                .setColor("Red")
                                                .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                                .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                                .setTimestamp()
                                        ],
                                        ephemeral: true
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(async (err) => {
                        if (String(err).includes("Error 404")) {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                        .setDescription("Could not find a registered Character in the Database. Make sure to use \`/register\` before you use this Command!")
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        } else {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                        .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        }
                    });
            return;
            case "remove":
                client.database.remPilot(user, pilot)
                    .then(async (msg) => {
                        await interaction.reply({
                            embeds: [
                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setColor("Green")
                                    .setDescription(`${msg}`)
                                    .setTimestamp()
                            ],
                            ephemeral: true
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(async (err) => {
                        if (String(err).includes("Error 404")) {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                        .setDescription("Could not find that Pilot in the Database!")
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        } else {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                        .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
    };
};
export default new Command();
```

register.js

```js
console.log("Register command loaded");

import { ApplicationCommandOptionType, EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js";
class Command {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "register";
        this.name_localizations = {
            "en-US": "register",
            "pt-BR": "registrar",
            "es-ES": "registrarse",
            "zh-CN": "注册",
            "ko": "등록"
        };
        this.description = "Registers your MIR4 Character",
        this.description_localizations = {
            "en-US": "Registers your MIR4 Character",
            "pt-BR": "Registrar seu personagem no MIR4",
            "es-ES": "Registrarse tu personaje de MIR4",
            "zh-CN": "注册您的 MIR4 角色",
            "ko": "MIR4 캐릭터 등록"
        };
        this.options = [
            {
                name: "name",
                name_localizations: {
                    "en-US": "name",
                    "pt-BR": "nome",
                    "es-ES": "nombre",
                    "zh-CN": "名称",
                    "ko": "이름"
                },
                description: "Your exact MIR4 Character Name",
                description_localizations: {
                    "en-US": "Your exact MIR4 Character Name",
                    "pt-BR": "Nome exato do seu personagem no MIR4",
                    "es-ES": "Tu nombre exacto de personaje de MIR4",
                    "zh-CN": "您精确的MIR4角色名称",
                    "ko": "정확한 MIR4 캐릭터 이름"
                },
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: "level",
                name_localizations: {
                    "en-US": "level",
                    "pt-BR": "nível",
                    "es-ES": "nivel",
                    "zh-CN": "水平",
                    "ko": "수평"
                },
                description: "Your MIR4 Character Level",
                description_localizations: {
                    "en-US": "Your MIR4 Character Level",
                    "pt-BR": "Seu nível de personagem MIR4",
                    "es-ES": "Tu nivel de personaje de MIR4",
                    "zh-CN": "您的MIR4角色级别",
                    "ko": "MIR4 캐릭터 레벨"
                },
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
                required: true,
                min_value: 95,
                max_value: 140,
            },
        ];
    };

    getCharacterData(name) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const api_url = "https://api.mir4info.com/v5/search/";
            const result = await fetch(api_url + name);
            const text = await result.text();
            const char = JSON.parse(text);
            if (char.isArray()) {
                if (char.length===1) {
                    resolve(char[0]);
                } else if (char.length>1) {
                    for (const character of char) {
                        if (character.match_type=="exact") {
                            resolve(character);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (char.error) {
                reject(char.error);
            }
        });
    };

    async run(client, interaction) {
        const member = interaction.member;
        const user = member.user;
        const name = interaction.getString("name");
        const level = interaction.getInteger("level");
        const roles = {
            tower1: "1130689026333085816",
            tower2: "1129258746854506687",
            tower3: "1130689120994349127"
        };
        this.getCharacterData(name)
            .then(char => {
                client.database.getCharacter(user, char)
                    .then(async () => {
                        //Trigger if the given Character was found in the Database
                        await interaction.reply({
                            embeds: [
                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setColor("Red")
                                    .setTitle("Error 409: Duplicate Character")
                                    .setDescription("A Character with that Name is already registered!")
                                    .setTimestamp()
                            ],
                            ephemeral: true
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(async (err) => {
                        if (String(err).includes("Error 404")) {
                            //Trigger if the Player does not have a Character
                            client.database.addCharacter(user, char)
                                .then(async () => {
                                    //Trigger if the Character has been added to the Database
                                    if (level>=95 && !level>120) {
                                        await member.roles.add(roles.tower1);
                                    }
                                    if (level>=115 && !level>130) {
                                        await member.roles.add(roles.tower2);
                                    }
                                    if (level<=120 && !level>140) {
                                        await member.roles.add(roles.tower3);
                                    }
                                    await interaction.reply({
                                        embeds: [
                                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                                .setColor("Aqua")
                                                .setTitle("Character Information")
                                                .addFields(
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Nick",
                                                        value: `\`${char.name}\``
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Class",
                                                        value: `\`${char.class_name}\``
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Power",
                                                        value: `\`${char.power}\``
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Region",
                                                        value: `\`${char.region_name}\``
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Server",
                                                        value: `\`${char.server_name}\``
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        name: "Clan",
                                                        value: `\`${char.clan_name}\``
                                                    }
                                                )
                                                .setThumbnail(client.class_icons[char.class_name])
                                                .setImage(client.class_banners[char.class_name])
                                        ]
                                    });
                                })
                                .catch(async (err1) => {
                                    //Trigger if there was an Error with trying to add the Character to the Database
                                    if (String(err1).includes("Error 409")) {
                                        await interaction.reply({
                                            embeds: [
                                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                                    .setColor("Red")
                                                    .setTitle("Error 409: Duplicate Character")
                                                    .setDescription("A Character with that Name is already registered!")
                                                    .setTimestamp()
                                            ],
                                            ephemeral: true
                                        });
                                    } else if (String(err1).includes("Error 400")) {
                                        await interaction.reply({
                                            embeds: [
                                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                                    .setColor("Red")
                                                    .setTitle(`${err1}`)
                                                    .setDescription("You may not register a Character that is not a member of a Clan in the Alliance!")
                                                    .setTimestamp()
                                            ],
                                            ephemeral: true
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        await interaction.reply({
                                            embeds: [
                                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                                    .setColor("Red")
                                                    .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                                    .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                                    .setTimestamp()
                                            ],
                                            ephemeral: true
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                        } else if (String(err).includes("Error 400")){
                            //Trigger if the Player already has a Character
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                        .setDescription("You may not register more than one Character!")
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        } else {
                            //Trigger if a Database Error occurred
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                        .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        }
                    });
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
                await interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setColor("Red")
                            .setDescription(`${err}`)
                            .setTimestamp()
                    ],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            });
    }
};

export default new Command();
```

When starting the bot in the terminal, it reports:

```
Client started
.-------------------------------------.
|               Events                |
|-------------------------------------|
|           Name            | Status  |
|---------------------------|---------|
| ready                     | Success |
| interactionCreate (Slash) | Success |
'-------------------------------------'
Connected to Database!
Collection(0) [Map] {}
```

But when going to the discord server, the bot is online but there are no commands for it.

(due to character limitations, I had to not send the psql.js and DiscordClient.js files
But it can be seen in the github link, the whole bot:
[DiscordClient.js](https://github.com/Julexar/MooMoo-Mir4/blob/root/structures/lib/DiscordClient.js)
[psql.js](https://github.com/Julexar/MooMoo-Mir4/blob/root/database/psql.js)

Comment: When you create a url to add the bot, make sure you add the scopes **bot** and **applications.commands**. **applications.commands** register the slash commands, so you might've just forgotten to add that.